# getDrawable Kotlin File Results in Resource Not found but works in Java file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I was banging my head for a few hours due to not able to load bitmap via drawable. To load the drawable via resource I am using

```
 ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
```

If I use this in any .kt file extension it never loads the drawable. I debugged it and came to know it leads to `resource not found exception.` 
[image: Kotlin Exception]
So to test the hypothesis. I created a new project having only 2 files. One Java and one Kotlin.
And somehow it works in java file.
[image: Java Working]
I am really clueless why it works in java and results in Exception in kotlin

---

So I think its a bug in Android studio while debugging, it doesn't give away the drawable.

Though My issue was I was creating a bitmap from vector drawable and somehow it wasn't drawing on canvas, so I started debugging it and came across resources not found. I tried with png and it worked. Even though it works in both kotlin and java i.e drawable object is created but debugger has some issue as posted in the question.

Comment: What is your build tools version?

Comment: com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 & Android Studio 3.5

Comment: I mean build tools version not gradle version in your module gradle file

Comment: oh. it's 29.0.2

Comment: I have check and found result drawable in return though my `Evaluate Expression shows not found`. Could you add your exception log?

Comment: try to assign the result in a variable check the result. `val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)`

Comment: it does return the drawable but it's empty. It wasn't showing anything, so I started debugging and found it's resulting in Resource not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202505/discussion-between-md-asaduzzaman-and-gautam).

Comment: will it be possible for you to post a link to reproducible sample project

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun getBitmapOfVectorDrawable(resourceId: Int, pContext: Context): Bitmap? {
    return try {
        val drawable: Drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(pContext, resourceId)!!
        if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
            drawable.bitmap
        } else if (drawable is VectorDrawableCompat || drawable is VectorDrawable) {
            val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
            drawable.draw(canvas)
            bitmap
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("unsupported drawable type")
        }
    } catch (ee: java.lang.Exception) {
        Log.e("TAG", ee.message)
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: val drawableBitmap = getBitmapOfVectorDrawable(R.drawable.cs_flip, this)

Comment: The question posted doesn't ask to return bitmap via vector. I wanted to know why it leads to exception while evaluating in debugger in kotlin file

Comment: Though My issue was I was creating a bitmap from vector drawable and somehow it wasn't drawing on canvas, so I started debugging it and came across resources not found. I tried with png and it worked. Even though it works in both kotlin and java i.e drawable object is created but debugger has some issue as posted in the question. Due to this I have posted answer